# Python Facial Recognition image compare :Reg

Tags: python, opencv

I want to compare an images with other list of images one by one then I want to know which image is having more percentage of similarities.
I tried to do the same with Python OPENCV `facerec_demo.py` but it is giving error as:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createEigenFaceRecognizer'
```

help me to solve this, share if have any working source code. And also suggest me if any alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem with the python port of OpenCV version 2.4.2.  As one of the developers explains [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/1215/how-to-compile-python-bindings-for-facerecognizer/), the solution is to upgrade to a newer version of OpenCV.